# What's the right way to publish Redis message from a Redis based NestJS Microservice

Tags: redis, microservices, nestjs

I built a sample Redis based Microservice with NestJS. It's fantastic and works great. In my microservice, after processing the message received over Redis (pub/sub), we publish our result to another Redis channel for a different microservice to pick.
What's the right way to publish? Are there any samples?

For my work, I used Redis package and published it (as opposed to ClientProxyFactory). Works fine and gets the job done.

```
import {
  ClientProxy,
  ClientProxyFactory,
  Transport,
} from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as redis from 'redis';
import { NVResponseDTO } from "../dto/nv.dto";

@Injectable()
export class NVPersistService {
  logger = new Logger('NVPersistService');
  private client: redis.RedisClient;

  constructor() {
    this.client = redis.createClient({port: 6379, host: 'localhost'});
    this.logger.log('Successfully created client for publish');
  }

  async publish(result: NVResponseDTO) {
    const channel = 'persistence';
    try {
      await this.client.publish(channel, JSON.stringify(result));
      this.logger.log(`Message sent`);
    } catch (e) {
      this.logger.error(e);
    }
  }
}
```

But is this the way to do it or should I use something like below

```
    this.client = ClientProxyFactory.create({
      transport: Transport.REDIS,
      options: {
        url: 'redis://localhost:6379',
      }
    });
    await this.client.connect();
    const channel = 'persistence';
    const status = await this.client.send<string, NVResponseDTO>(channel, result);
    this.logger.log(`Status of send - ${status}`);
```

*Note: Above code did not work for me, hence used Redis directly. Any guidance would be much appreciated*

Comment: Dose [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-redis) solves the problem?

Comment: @LeibaleEidelman is pretty much the same as my solution above, done with a npm choice